# Set parameter in FormData for dynamic fields (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am getting an issue on setting up the form data for dynamic fields included `input[type="file"]`.

In my word, Dynamic fields mean generating the fields with the loop of an array.

I tried the for loop than data is not going to the server.

I am using Vue and Vuex.

Only the value from the last loop is going on the database.

```js
let formdata = new FormData();
for(var i = 0; i< this.assignmentForm.length; i++) {
  formdata.append('file', this.$refs.assignmentFile[i].files[0]);
  formdata.append('name', this.$refs.assignmentName[i].value);
  formdata.append('comment', this.$refs.assignmentComment[i].value);
  formdata.append('assignment_solution', this.respondId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correctly using `.append` instead of `.set`, but you forgot that variables should be arrays, thus their keys should be `file[]`, `name[]`, `comment[]` and `assignment_solution[]` respectively.

This way your backend will correctly recognize that they are indeed arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending multiple files using the same name. Only the last addition will reach your server.

You have at least 2 options:

1. Give unique names to each field. Something similar to this

   formdata.append('file' + i, this.$refs.assignmentFile[i].files[0]);

Notice the concatenation of file with the index variable.

2. Use the **array notation** for the fields’ names. This is compatible with how PHP handled POST variables.

   formdata.append('file[]', this.$refs.assignmentFile[i].files[0]);

Notice the square brackets in the name **file[]**.

You need to do this for all the fields: file, name, comments.